# could anyone tell me where I can download a FREE software that simulates a CISCO router?

Tags: router, simulation

I am searching for a free Cisco router simulator that has good features.

Comment: What do you mean 'simulates' ?

Comment: well, just like a flight simulator lets you practise flying a plane, a cisco router simulation software lets you practise on a software cisco router...just as if it was a real router...it lets you practise the commands, link to other (software) routers..etc...

Comment: Yes, I see. Paid to much attention to the word 'router' and not enough to 'Cisco'. You're not talking about cheap simple hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Free Router Simulators](http://www.certification-crazy.net/router_simulators.htm) at [`certification-crazy.net`](http://www.certification-crazy.net/)

> Obviously, where possible, training on the real thing when it comes to Cisco routers and other hardware is better when it comes to preparing for an exam. But when the budget doesn't stretch that far, or you only have limited access to hardware, then router simulators are the next best thing. So following are a number of free router simulators that you can download, trial and practice with for your Cisco certification.

And, there is a list of some 6 simulators -- see if you one of them suits your needs.
One of them refers to the [RouterSimulator.CertExams](http://routersimulator.certexams.com/) demo [download](http://routersimulator.certexams.com/ccna-simulator-download/download-router-simulator.html).

Comment: I've also downloaded several of the simulators on the certification-crazy.net, but they have limited functions. I was hoping someone here knows of other simulators that can be legally downloaded. THank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gns3.net/

You need the IOS images(think "roms") from Cisco, but they can be hard to come by if you don't have a support contract...

Comment: thank you justin. I've seen that website too, but since I can't obtain an IOS , I didn't download it. :)